# How many trees are there on vertex set $[n]$ that contain a given edge $uv$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

> How many trees are there on vertex set $[n]$ that contain a given edge $uv$?

If we glue the vertex $u$ and $v$ with an edge then there are $n-1$ vertices and using the Cayley's formula there are total $(n-1)^{(n-3)}$ trees with vertex set $[n-1]$ and a given edge $uv$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2204160 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832958/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575163/ (These were found [using the Approach0 search engine](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%242n%5E%7Bn-3%7D%24%2C%20tree&p=1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way to perform the count is to count trees with a distinguished edge. As there are $n^{n-2}$ trees and each has $n-1$ edges, there are 
$n^{n-2}\cdot(n-1)$ such trees.
By symmetry, each of the $n\choose 2$ potential edges is distinguished the same number of times. Thus we arrive at
$$ \frac{n^{n-2}\cdot(n-1)}{n\choose 2}=2n^{n-3}$$
trees where $uv$ happens to be the distinguished edge.